# Django South: schemamigration hanging for model changes

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am following the [South tutorial](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html).  I am able to do the steps under "The First Migration" successfully.  However, when I modify the schema and run schemamigration again:

```
python manage.py schemamigration southtut --auto
```

the command never completes.  I don't get any error messages.  Here's the modification I made to the model in the South tutorial:

```
class Knight(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    of_the_round_table = models.BooleanField()
    foo = models.IntegerField() # added this field
```

Here's a log of the initial migration:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration southtut --initial
Creating migrations directory at 'c:\Users\jp\Documents\project\southtut\migrations'...
Creating __init__.py in 'c:\Users\jp\Documents\project\southtut\migrations'...
 + Added model southtut.Knight
Created 0001_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate southtut
(django-test)
jp@jp-PC ~/project
$
(django-test)
jp@jp-PC ~/project
$ python manage.py migrate southtut
Running migrations for southtut:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > southtut:0001_initial
 - Loading initial data for southtut.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

Here's an update.

I am using `msys`.  I noticed that when I entered `python` (without any arguments), it also hung.  When I used `cmd`, running `python` did not hang.  When I did `python manage.py schemamigration southtut --auto` in cmd, the command completed.  I had to install [virtualenvwrapper-win](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win), though, since I use virtualenvwrapper.  Does anyone know why running `schememigration` with `--auto` hangs on msys?  Or specifically, why running `python` hangs?  I can run `startapp`, `syncdb`, and `runserver` without issues.  I would prefer not to use cmd.

Another update:
This is definitely related to the problem of python not being interactive.  I installed msys on my work PC which has Windows 7, and I can run python form msys without problem.  The problem PC is Vista, my home PC.  This definitely used to work before.  The problem still happens even if I uninstall and reinstall msys.  I think OpenSSH for Windows may have caused this problem because that clobbered my PATH.

`python -i` works fine, though.  If I do `python -i manage.py schemamigration southtut --auto` the migration file is created, but I get the python prompt at the end.  I guess I could live with this, but this definitely used to work before, and this is driving me nuts.

Comment: Have you executed `manage.py migrate` after that?

Comment: Yes.  I updated the OP with the log.

Comment: you should have 2 migrations in your /migrations/ folder. Do you ?

Comment: No.  Again, `python manage.py schemamigration southtut --auto` never completes.  It hangs.  I don't see any messages.  Therefore, the second migration is never created.  Only the migration file from the initial migration is created.